# scipy -- how to convert a function result to array

Tags: python, scipy

Hello i have the function Walk1d which then i want to calculate the cumsum.
I use Walk1d=lambda n: sc.cumsum(steps(n))  .The result is an array but when i am trying Walk1d.cumsum() it doesn't work because type(Walk1d) is a function.
If i try sc.array(Walk1d).cumsum() it gives me : at 0x3798488>
How can i handle this?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy as sc


steps=lambda m: 2*sc.random.random_integers(0,1,size=m)-1
Walk1d=lambda n: sc.cumsum(steps(n))

print(sc.array(Walk1d).cumsum())
```

Thanks!

Comment: Woudn't it be much clearer if you used regular function definitions like `def steps(m): blah blah`? Your code indeed is full of one-liners, but I don't think this is an advantage in this case, or in Python generically speaking. If you expand this in more lines, your error messages will be clear (if any) and people will find much easier to help you. Just a thought.

Comment: I did it like this because its small program and the definitions are small.

Comment: @George:  Nothing is stopping you from writing `def steps(m): return 2*sc.random.random_integers(0,1,size=m)-1`.  Still a one liner.

Comment: @George : I have to watch myself all the times for trying to do the same, but the habit of writing legible (instead of one-liner-infested) code is well worth the discipline, even if your programs are small. Reading speed is not a bottleneck, and compilers don't mind if code is sparse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Walk1d` is a function taking an argument.  You have to call the function and pass in an argument to get a result, for example

```
print(Walk1d(10).cumsum())
```

Comment: Yes ,you are right!I missed it!However,it still gives <type function>.Is there a way to convert it to array?If i want to retrieve for example from the above the Walk1d[0:3] how can i do that?

Comment: Ok,i found it! I name x=sc.array(Walk1d(10)) and then i do x[1:3]

Answer (score 0):

The function `Walk1d` needs to be called with a parameter `n`:

```
print(sc.array(Walk1d(10)).cumsum())
```